# in SQL, how do I get min starting and max ending date for each consecutive position an employee works?

Tags: sql

I have some problem, I want to get earliest work beginning, and latest work ending for each position.

Data in Table:

```
   EMPLOYEE_ID      PCN         POSITION    WorkBEG                 WorkEND  
    --16156         056-240-35  056FOOD706  2014-09-18 00:00:00.000 2015-06-04 00:00:00.000  
    --16156         056-240-35  056FOOD706  2015-08-20 00:00:00.000 2015-08-23 00:00:00.000  
    --16156         057-240-35  057FOOD706  2015-08-24 00:00:00.000 2016-06-02 00:00:00.000  
    --16156         057-240-35  057FOOD706  2016-08-18 00:00:00.000 2017-06-02 00:00:00.000  
    --16156         TEMP        715SUMREMB  2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-08-13 00:00:00.000  
    --16156         057-240-35  057FOOD706  2017-08-14 00:00:00.000 2018-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

-- my query
-- 3 rows

```
select m.ID as EMPLOYEE_ID,  
  p.PCN,  
  p.POSITION,  
  min(p.CALC_BEG) as WorkBEG,  
  max(p.CALC_END) as WorkEND  
from hr_empmstr m  
  inner join hr_emppay p on p.ID = m.ID  
where (m.LASTDAYWRK is null  
  or m.LASTDAYWRK >= dateadd(y,-5,getdate()))  
and p.REC_TYPE = 'PM'  
and p.CALC_END <> p.CALC_BEG  
and m.ID = '16156'  
group by m.ID, p.PCN, p.POSITION  
order by m.ID,  WorkBEG;
```

results:

```
--EMPLOYEE_ID   PCN         POSITION    WorkBEG                 WorkEND  
--16156         056-240-35  056FOOD706  2014-09-18 00:00:00.000 2015-08-23 00:00:00.000  
--16156         057-240-35  057FOOD706  2015-08-24 00:00:00.000 2018-06-01 00:00:00.000  
--16156         TEMP        715SUMREMB  2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-08-13 00:00:00.000
```

trying to get:

```
--EMPLOYEE_ID   PCN         POSITION    POS_LONG                        WorkBEG                 WorkEND  
--16156         056-240-35  056FOOD706  FOOD SERV/CAFE HELP             2014-09-18 00:00:00.000 2015-08-23 00:00:00.000  
--16156         057-240-35  057FOOD706  FOOD SERV/CAFE HELP             2015-08-24 00:00:00.000 2017-06-02 00:00:00.000  
--16156         TEMP        715SUMREMB  SUMMER EMPLOYEE                 2017-06-05 00:00:00.000 2017-08-13 00:00:00.000  
--16156         057-240-35  057FOOD706  FOOD SERV/CAFE HELP             2017-08-14 00:00:00.000 2018-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: There's no `POS_LONG` in any of your described sources.

Comment: Which dbms???????

Comment: db is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 I believe

Comment: pos_long is just a description for the position - I took that lookup table out of the SQL I posted to reduce clutter